# Stripe express or custom onboarding using CURL

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Below is a CURL method for Sign up boarding for Stripe. This is fine for onboarding the main account holder. What if I wanted to onboard a separate user with a difference stripe connected account? How would I pass the account ID for this? I've been following the documentation example at the following address.

https://medium.com/@joel.kazadi/how-to-set-up-stripe-connect-express-the-easy-way-deb039e3b8a1

```
<?php
    
    
if (isset($_GET['code'])) { // Redirect w/ code
    $code = $_GET['code'];
}
else
{
    echo "Error"; exit;
}
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "client_secret=STRIPE_SECRET_KEY=".$code."&grant_type=authorization_code");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
header('location: https://LINK_TO_PAGE_OR_WEBSITE_YOU_SEND_USERS_TO_AFTER_AUTHENTICATION');
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
}
curl_close ($ch);
    
    
?>
The Link to Onboard - 
h t t p s://connect.stripe.com/express/oauth/authorize?redirect_uri=https://LINK_TO_PHP_FILE&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&state=111
```

Answer (score 0):

The post you reference is a bit outdated, using the OAuth approach that is no longer the recommended pattern.

Instead, the [updated recommended integration](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts) is to follow these steps:

1/ [Create the Express account](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts#create-account) via the Accounts API

```
$stripe->accounts->create(['type' => 'express']);
```

2/ [Create an Account Link](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts#create-link) (a short-lived URL for entering the onboarding flow)

```
$stripe->accountLinks->create(
  [
    'account' => 'acct_1234',
    'refresh_url' => 'https://example.com/reauth',
    'return_url' => 'https://example.com/return',
    'type' => 'account_onboarding',
  ]
);
```

3/ Have your user [follow that link](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts#redirect-link) either via click or redirect.

With this pattern, you have explicit control over using an existing account vs creating a new one based on your requirements.

Comment: Can I follow the same protocol by creating a custom account instead of the express account?

Comment: You should edit out your secret key in that message and roll your key: https://stripe.com/docs/keys#rolling-keys

Comment: The `StripeClient` error suggests you don't have `stripe-php` installed/loaded properly yet. See here: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/README.md#composer